# Access method from event handler Vue.JS

Tags: javascript, php, events, vue.js, handler

I don't know how to explain it but i just want to ask why i cannot execute the getTransaction method from the $on event handler. The console will just display error like that.

[image]

```
var transactioninfo = {
  template: `<p>hello</p>`,
  methods: {
    getTransaction: function() {
      alert('test')
    }
  },
  mounted: function() {
    event_broadcaster.$on('showSelected', function(payload) {
      this.transactioninfo.getTransaction();
    })
  },
  data () {
    return {
      Transaction: [],
    }
  },
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are changing the context of `this` when you pass in a callback using `function` syntax. Change it to es6 arrow notation and it should work:

```
event_broadcaster.$on('showSelected', (payload) => {
    this.getTransaction();
})
```